# Ping and TTL-expired packets: no round trip time shown

Tags: ip, ping, icmp, ttl

If I run `ping` with packets that expire at a given hop, `ping` won't compute any round trip time:

```
~# ping www.google.com -t 3 -v
PING www.google.com (173.194.40.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
From te1-3-marseille1-rtr-021.noc.renater.fr (193.51.189.25) icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
From te1-3-marseille1-rtr-021.noc.renater.fr (193.51.189.25) icmp_seq=2 Time to live exceeded
From te1-3-marseille1-rtr-021.noc.renater.fr (193.51.189.25) icmp_seq=3 Time to live exceeded
From te1-3-marseille1-rtr-021.noc.renater.fr (193.51.189.25) icmp_seq=4 Time to live exceeded
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3003ms
```

Is there any way to show it?

Comment: Why is my question off topic, according to somebody?

Answer (score 0):

No, because there was no response packet so no round trip to time.

If you want to know the round trip time to the 3rd node, use `traceroute` to figure out the ip of that hop and ping that ip instead.

Comment: Yeah, of course I can use `traceroute`. Matching responses is straightforward, that's why I am a bit surprised it isn't displayed.

Comment: Actually, there is a response packet. It is a ICMP with TTL Exceeded (Type 11).  The computer has everything it needs to calculate the round trip time.  In fact, this is how Windows Tracert works.